# How can I place a div directly under a div that is being created by an ngFor directive?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `div` that is created by an `ngFor` directive. This `div` contains a clickable edit icon. As it stands, each `div` has a `col-xs-4` class which sets the divs side by side when there are more than one. My goal is to create a `div` that appears directly at the bottom of a specific `div`, when it's edit button is pressed. So the original divs will still line up side by side, while the new `div` will appear at the bottom of the specific `div` which edit button you just clicked.

Here is a stackblitz of what I tried so far.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2j8cjr

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you paste some code showing what you are talking about?

Comment: Can you post some code or create a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com  of whatever you have tried

Comment: @SachinGupta here is a stackblitz of what I have tried so far. My goal is to have the  editing content div to show and push down  the send row of divs when the edit button is clicked. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2j8cjr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code would be helpful here to work with, but generally it would look something like this...

```
<div class="edit-wrapper col-xs-4" *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="edit-icon" (click)="item.editing = true"></div>
  <div class="edit-content" *ngIf="item.editing">..editing content...</div>
</div>
```

This ngFors over your items and puts a wrapper div that contains both your edit icon and edit div within.  Clicking the button sets an editing property on the item which will reveal the editing div.  This is basic and likely needs tweaks to meet your specific requirements, but I did what I could with what you gave.

Comment: I tried your solution. The editing div only shows up on the divs at the bottom of the two rows. How can I have the editing divs push down the second row so they can be visible from the first row. Here is a stackblitz of what I have done so far. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2j8cjr

Comment: look again at what i did... you don't have the page set up correctly.

Comment: I was messing around with it. Can you check now?

Comment: yea, i mean its sort of working but you just have a tangle of css issues.  You should try using flexbox instead of this bootstrap nonsense.